# What is the method behind calculating a distance matrix?

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

Do you know if for the creation centroids or nearest distance (or whatever) is used?

How do I know what is happening?

Couldn't find anything specific in the documentation.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Which tool are you using? [Distance matrix](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisdistancematrix) is only for point inputs?